# Show HTML objects

Tags: javascript, html

I wish to show out other objects when the onclick function is clicked. When i click that button, it will hide one object and show two other objects. I have already set the style.visibility to visible. But the show two object does not works.

Update Sample:

```
<input type="submit" id="show" name="show" value="show" onclick="RemoveDoc(); document.getElementById('docname').style.visibility='hidden'; document.getElementById('browse').style.visibility='visible'; return false;" />
//browse input
<input type ="file" name="browse" id="browse">
```

Method 2:

```
 //Using my RemoveDoc() function, I want the button of browse being show out.
 function RemoveDoc(Doc)
 {
xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp1.open("GET","functions/remove.php?Doc="+Doc,true);
xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp1.readyState==4 && xmlhttp1.status==200)
    {
            //when i run debugging, it says that the style of null..
    document.getElementById("browse").style.visibility='visible';

    }
}
xmlhttp1.send();

    return false;
    }
    </script>
```

I tried two methods which both also cant show the browse button.
It should call out my visible on browse object as it's visible.. kindly advise.

Comment: Could you post all relevant html code and also your function `RemoveDoc`?

Comment: @Neal I'm guessing he's tried the code that he's posted.

Comment: @Hans there is no full code there that I can see.

Comment: my removeDoc() will not affect my show html objects right ?

Comment: @JLearner if there is an exception in removeDoc it will prevent the show lines from executing.

Comment: @jbabey i have added my removeDoc() code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/y3Bad/

A few things: you should include the visibility code inside of your `removeDoc` function, and bind the handler from javascript, not in markup. Also, your variable `xmlhttp1` is an implicit global. Your `removeDoc` function takes a parameter, `Doc`, but you never pass anything to it. Finally, `removeDoc` makes an ajax call, which is asynchronous, so your line of code to show the browse button will not execute immediately, and may never execute at all if your ajax calls fails.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="show" name="show" value="show" />
```

JS:

```
​document.getElementById('show').onclick = function () {
    // use display instead of visibility if you don't want the hidden element to take up space

    // setting visibility to empty string will show the element
    document.getElementById('browse').style.visibility = '';
};​
```

Comment: So you are saying that i should createa new onclick function? Because my onclick is link with removeDoc now..

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Seems like it cant find my browse id.

Answer (score 0):

I use these two functions:

```
function hide(objId) {
    document.getElementById(objId).style.display="none";
}

function show(objId) {
    document.getElementById(objId).style.display="";
}
```

Comment: display: none means the element will not be displayed and will not take up space on the page. visibility: hidden means the element will not be displayed but it will still occupy the same space on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use jQuery, something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/7fJuu/

Comment: I think i know why. Because the objects is inside my if statement. Can i choose to hide it this values without clicking first?

Comment: you can hide objects on page load event, using jQuery: 
`$(function() {
 // here you can call hide() for object 
 // e.g. $(#show).hide(); - this will hide button with the id="show" 
});`